# How to position the second element to the top, without knowing elements height

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve a difficult thing with only CSS. I've this HTML code

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="a block">A</div>
    <div class="b block">B</div>
    <div class="c block">C</div>
    <div class="d block">D</div>
</div>
```

A element is before B to achieve this layout on mobile:
[image: mobile layout]

What I'm trying to achieve is the following layout on desktops:
[image: desktop layout]

I prefer not to use javascript, also I don't know `.block` dimensions (their content may vary). So, on B element, I cannot use nor a negative `margin` (because I don't know A block height), nor `position: absolute` (because B content height might overflow wrapper height).
What I know is B block width in pixels.

Sadly I cannot use CSS3 [flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) nor [grid layout](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid).

I've created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gbonanome/5W76y/4/) to use with HTML and CSS.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What would you like to happen when B will be bigger as the wrapper?

Comment: The wrapper should always contains B. I cannot let B overflow. :( Sorry it seems really tricky. I think I can accept also "is not possible" as an answer.

Comment: What i mean is: may the wrapper be bigger depending on the B height or do you want it never be bigger as ADC together(or you use more blocks)?

Comment: It may be bigger. The wrapper height should change according to the tallest elemnt (.b or a+c+d).

Comment: So this would work right? http://jsfiddle.net/5W76y/19/. Posted by @Danko

Comment: Sorry, it could work but I must use B column width in pixels and this could break the percentage solution.

Answer (score 2):

Without using any `positioning`...using your existing markup, here is your working [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5W76y/15/)

You just need to play around with the `float` and `clear`ing them wherever required!

Amended **CSS**

```
.a, .c,  .d {
    float:right;
    width:70%;
}

.b{
    float:left;
    width:28%;
    height:100%;
}


@media (max-width: 400px) {
   .a {
    float:right;
    width:100%;
}
  .d {
    clear:both;
    width:100%;
}

 .c,.b{
    float:left;
    width:49%;
    height:100%;
}
```

**EDIT**

If you want **B** to have full height of parent div when in `> 400px media query`, then [check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5W76y/22/)

CSS to change:

```
.wrapper, .table {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    height:186px;/* if u want B to have full height of parent div in computer mode, then this must have a value in pixels*/

}
```

Comment: @Danko : update the code with B having full height of the parent div...and finally i got one answer b4 u!! :)

Comment: Sorry, the .b block `width` is set in pixels, so I prefer to not use percentage.

Comment: Yes, is here: http://jsfiddle.net/gbonanome/5W76y/4/ With the percentage solution is a lot difficult to mantain consistency on  different viewports. The white space between B column and A+C+D column may vary a lot.

Comment: @GiulioBonanome : you have to create more breakout points if you have to use `px` only!!

Answer (score 0):

The beautiful thing about CSS is having multiple ways of doing things.  In this case, you can keep things simple by using outer containers and float lefts:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="floatLeft">
    <div class="b block">B</div>
  </div>
  <div class="floatLeft">
    <div class="a block">A</div>
    <div class="c block">C</div>
    <div class="d block">D</div>
  </div>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8spqs/

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code for DESKTOPS if you are new to css and cannot use an external stylesheet:

```
 <div class ="wrapper1" style="float:left;width:200px;margin-right:10px;">
    <div class="b block" style="width:200px;height:200px;background-color:pink;">     
    B             
    </div>
 </div>

 <div class ="wrapper2" style="float:left;width:150px;
  background-color:gray;">
<div class="a block" style="width:200px;height:200px;
 background-color:yellow;">
    A
    </div>  
    <div class="c block" style="width:200px;height:200px;background-color:gold;">
    C
    </div>
    <div class="d block" style="width:200px;height:200px;background-color:purple;"> 
    D
    </div>
   </div>
```